# What am I this time?

Tags: riddle

I can hold the heaviest of all objects,

but will falter to the lightest of all objects.

I prefer long and skinny rather than short and thick

since it is to my taste

which you cannot sense

You can see me as far the eye can see

 in the seven seas

 or the seven continents

Precious by nature

 yet never rare

 I seem to be more desired than gold

You are here because of me

 and I am certainly not here because of you

As a group, I can be a force to reckon with

 yet I can be gentler than a breeze

 as every organism adores me

What am I this time?

Hint 1:

> I can be wavy or straight, but always true to the color blue

Hint 2:

> I'm critical to your own survival and like to fall from the sky sometimes

**NOTE:** After five days the above hint was posted, I will answer the question. Please hurry!

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: It wasn't me (I'm just seeing this puzzle now), but it may be because two people have basically already solved the puzzle with water/ice, but now we're waiting for someone to come along and decipher the last of your clues.  Once the puzzle is solved (and rationalized somehow, even if not 100% in line with what you had in mind) it is not fun to wait around for people to guess what OP had in mind for each nuanced clue.

Comment: Well the downvote was well before all the answers so not really...

Comment: it... really feels like... somebody already got the answer... to a degree that should be considered sufficient...like.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the answer is

> **Water.**
>
>  The ocean can hold the world's heaviest objects, but will falter due to the 'lightest' of all objects -- the sun. (In this case, 'lightest' refers to the brightness and not the weight of an object.)
>
>  Long and skinny can refer to the throat that drinks it, or even the shape of waves in the ocean.
>
>  The 'taste you cannot sense' refers to the fact that water doesn't have a taste.
>
>  Water obviously exists in the seven seas, and on every continent.
>
>  It is precious by nature and worth more than money, yet (most) people have access to it.
>
>  Water predates humans but humans wouldn't be here without water, as they need it to survive.
>
>  Finally, bodies of water (such as the ocean) are a force to be reckoned with, yet small amounts of water are harmless and necessary for human survival.

Comment: Close but you got the first two clues wrong

Comment: Is the answer right, but the reasoning incorrect?

Comment: Clue1 - think with the other common name of Water

Comment: @Alex Are you referring to oxygen?

Comment: More like hydrogen (lighter)

Comment: You are getting very close...

Comment: Even if he doesn't have all of the clues right, he has the correct answer so in my opinion this should be the accepted answer

Comment: is this liquid rather than water?

Comment: I will accept this answer but the first clue is to be about density

Comment: Could "hold the heaviest" refer to Blue Whales, the heaviest **animal** (not object) which water holds? Or some specific ship which has been declared the heaviest manmade object?

Answer (score 4):

It may not be the right answer, but it more or less fits on all accounts.

> **ice**

I can hold the heaviest of all objects,
but will falter to the lightest of all objects.

> It is tough and withstands heavy loads. However, lightest of all objects can be interpreted as fire (also in the Classical 4-element model), which defeats ice.

I prefer long and skinny rather than short and thick
since it is to my taste
which you cannot sense

> It forms icicles -- long and skinny. It's also tasteless.

You can see me as far the eye can see
in the seven seas
or the seven continents

> All the continents are sometimes covered in ice. It's also in the highest clouds. Layers of ice also cover oceans.

Precious by nature
yet never rare
I seem to be more desired than gold

> This one is a stretch. Due to global warming, we are very protective of the polar caps.

You are here because of me
and I am certainly not here because of you

> Evolution of man occured after the latest ice age, so we are here because of ice.

As a group, I can be a force to reckon with
yet I can be gentler than a breeze
as every organism adores me

> Huge boulders of ice (or hail) are dangerous. Gentle snow, on the other hand... is adorable :)

Comment: Ask any thirsty person in a desert under the afternoon sun, I'm pretty sure they would desire ice more than gold.

Comment: I'd say this for water, asking for ice is a bit much. I mean, why not ask for a 5-course meal with a nice wine, while you're at it :)

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer is  (you are)

> Cloud

---

I found it most suited with the below sentences

`but will falter to the lightest of all objects. /
 You can see me as far the eye can see  /
 Precious by nature  /
 and I am certainly not here because of you  /
 As a group, I can be a force to reckon with  /
 yet I can be gentler than a breeze  /`


And this Hint  **I can be wavy or straight, but always true to the color blue**
 
made me sure of my answer. : )

Answer (score 2):

I think that the answer is

> Space

I can hold the heaviest of all objects, 
but will falter to the lightest of all objects.

> Space have galaxies. And if you put something into the space, then the space is covered

I prefer long and skinny rather than short and thick 
since it is to my taste 
which you cannot sense

> The galaxies are spiral in shape which is long (not short). Space is vacuum. So there is no taste

You can see me as far the eye can see 
in the seven seas 
or the seven continents

> We can see the sky from anywhere.

Precious by nature 
yet never rare 
I seem to be more desired than gold

> We always need some space (area) to live first. It is abundant on earth

You are here because of me 
and I am certainly not here because of you

> No space = no earth = no life

As a group, I can be a force to reckon with 
yet I can be gentler than a breeze 
as every organism adores me

> Space is vast and many explosion like supernova happens in space. However it is also very silent there. And every person needs space in his own life.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are

> Carbon

I can hold the heaviest of all objects

> Diamonds, made of carbon, are the hardest known material (though some people only say they are the the hardest *naturally occurring* material, and [there seems to be some controversy](https://van.physics.illinois.edu/qa/listing.php?id=613) as to whether they are in fact the hardest), so a large diamond would presumably be capable of holding very heavy objects. I assume that "heaviest of all objects" (which if interpreted literally would be something like a supermassive black hole?) is meant metaphorically or as hyperbole.

But will falter to the lightest of all objects

> The lightest of all objects is hydrogen. This could be referring to a chemical reaction that takes place when carbon comes in contact with hydrogen. Alternatively, graphite, also made of carbon, is one of the *softest* materials, so this could refer to a pencil coming in contact with a sheet of paper (which is among the lightest of objects on the scale experienced by humans).

I prefer long and skinny rather than short and thick

> Pencils, which have a graphite core, are long and skinny.

since it is to my taste
which you cannot sense

> Not sure about this.

You can see me as far the eye can see
in the seven seas
or the seven continents

> Carbon is one of the most abundant elements, both on Earth and in the universe. Wherever you are and in any direction you look, you will see it.

Precious by nature
yet never rare
I seem to be more desired than gold

> Diamonds, one of the forms in which carbon is found in Nature, are precious and more desired than gold. Yet carbon is abundant and not rare.

You are here because of me
and I am certainly not here because of you

> All life on Earth is carbon based. Carbon existed long before humans, or even the Earth, did.

As a group, I can be a force to reckon with

> Carbon belongs to a group of elements known as the [carbon group,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_group) which also contains important elements like silicon and germanium, very useful semiconductors, and tin and lead.

yet I can be gentler than a breeze
as every organism adores me

> Not sure what the first line is referring to. Organisms need carbon to survive.

Comment: Nope, not carbon

Comment: Is this anywhere near the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> **Air**: It can hold heaviest of all objects and will falter to the lightest, long and skinny can be referred to the planes like structure like a paper plane, it is everywhere and precious, we are here because of it. It's a force in group like storm and every organism adores it for their survival.

Answer (score 0):

It has got to be

> Rain

*I can hold the heaviest of all objects,
but will falter to the lightest of all objects.*

> Not sure what the heavest object is but the lightest object is air, and rain gets deviated by air.

*I prefer long and skinny rather than short and thick
since it is to my taste
which you cannot sense*

> Not sure what this means...

*You can see me as far the eye can see
in the seven seas
or the seven continents*

> It rains pretty much everywhere and when it is raining, you can see it all around.

*Precious by nature
yet never rare
I seem to be more desired than gold*

> People like rain?

*You are here because of me
and I am certainly not here because of you*

> No explanation needed here.

*As a group, I can be a force to reckon with
yet I can be gentler than a breeze
as every organism adores me*

> If it rains really heavily, the force of the water is huge. But a gentle drizzle feels like...mother nature's love?

Comment: i think this is the one